# Removing out-of-order elements from a timeline

Tags: algorithm, numbers, series

Imagine there's a device recording your birthday parties, and keeps a history of them, in the order they were recorded:

1. Your 10th birthday party
2. Your 11th birthday party
3. Your 12th birthday party
4. Your 13th birthday party

**Catch 1**: But the device is buggy because sometimes it records an invalid birthday (event #2 below):

1. Your 10th birthday party
2. Your 17th birthday party
3. Your 12th birthday party
4. Your 13th birthday party

**Catch 2**: And, of course, you don't always have birthday parties, so a list could also look like this:

1. Your 10th birthday party
2. Your 11th birthday party
3. Your 12th birthday party
4. Your 14th birthday party

---

Obviously, this is an algorithm involving a number series. Sorry for the intro, but I wanted to have a "realistic" scenario because what I wanted to do would look almost random. I could rephrase it to `Given a graph plot, I want to go from the lowest point upwards, without ever having to go down`. For example, in the plot below, 5, 8 and 11 are invalid, and need to be taken out, in order for me to `go up from the lowest point, without ever going downwards`:

[image: i don't even know what i'm saying anymore]

So the algo would clean `[1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7, 11, 9]` into `[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]`.

Here are some samples of what I would like the algo to do:

```js
doAlgo([]) == []
doAlgo([1]) == [1]
doAlgo([1, 2]) == [1, 2]
doAlgo([2, 2]) == [2, 2]
doAlgo([2, 2, 1]) == [1]
doAlgo([2, 1]) == [1]
doAlgo([1, 3, 2]) == [1, 2]
doAlgo([1, 2, 3, 4, 1]) == [1, 1]
doAlgo([5, 2, 3, 4, 1]) == [1]
doAlgo([5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]) == [1, 2]
doAlgo([5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1]) == [1, 1]
doAlgo([1,2,3,4,5,8,6,7,8,9]) == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: [1,2,5,8,11] would also be a monontone increasing subsequence of your input data, could you say something about why you prefer  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9] ?

Comment: Anyway,  if you are looking for the longest such sequence your problem is formally known as "Longest increasing subsequence" and can be solved by DP. You can easily find explanations and examples online.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianSloper. You gave me some ideas, but I don't think a LIS algo would fit the bill. E.g. `[1,2,3,4,3,5]` should yield `[1,2,3,3,5]`, acting like `4` was a mistake. LIS would instead yield `1,2,3,4`. As for why I prefer `[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]`, see my "birthday party" analogy.

Comment: Why would 1,2,3,3,5 be a good fit for your birthday analogy?  its not like you celebrated 3 twice.  LIS would yield 1,2,3,4,5 which is the longest subsequence.   Subsequences do not need to be consecutitive elements in the original sequence.

Comment: I don't think your birthday party analogy adresses why you think one increasing subsequence is better than another.